# Firebase http function finishing before http request library returns data

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, google-cloud-functions

I have an HTTP triggered Firebase function, which uses the request library https://github.com/request/request to make an HTTP post to another API. The logs show the POST request is returning the correct data but the Firebase function is finishing before the Async POST returns the data.
How do I make the overall function wait for the POST request?

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
var requestDependency = require('request');

exports.XXXXXXXXXX = functions.https.onRequest((request, response) => {

    var answer = 'testo';
    var jsonResponse = null;
    var jsonData = 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX';
    let url = "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX"; //or production  

    requestDependency.post({

        headers: {    
            'content-type': 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX'  ,
            'Accept': 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX',
            'XXXXXXXXXX-Access-Token': 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX'
        },

        url: url,  
        body: jsonData 

    }, function(error, response, body) { 

        if (error) {  
            console.log('errrrrrrrror1')
        } else {
            jsonResponse = body;
            console.log(jsonResponse); <-----Shows correct data returned
            console.log('Done.');
            answer = jsonResponse;
            console.log('TEST: ' + answer)
        }
    });

    console.log("Performing search");
    response.send(cardName+" "+jsonResponse); <---jsonResponse not populated
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/terminate-functions), HTTP functions are terminated when a response is sent to the client.  This means your call to response.send() is effectively terminating the function.

The problem is that the call to `post()` is asynchronous and returns immediately while the HTTP request continues in the background.  Function execution continues right after the post.  This means your sent response is almost certainly going to get executed before the HTTP request finishes.

If you want to wait for the HTTP request to finish, put your response to the client **inside** the callback that handles the response from the HTTP request.

```
function(error, response, body) { 
    if (error) {  
        console.log('errrrrrrrror1')
        // send an error response here
    } else {
        jsonResponse = body;
        console.log(jsonResponse); <-----Shows correct data returned
        console.log('Done.');
        answer = jsonResponse;
        console.log('TEST: ' + answer)
        // send an success response here
    }
});
```

Also watch this video series to get a better grasp on how Cloud Functions works: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7IkUgCLr5oA&index=2&list=PLl-K7zZEsYLkPZHe41m4jfAxUi0JjLgSM

Comment: When I move 

response.send(cardName+" "+jsonResponse);

to inside where you commented in your example, I get this error 

TypeError: response.send is not a function
    at Request._callback (/user_code/index.js:34:22)
    at Request.self.callback 

How can I reference the response.send from inside where your comments are?

Comment: Now you have two response variables representing different things.  Rename one of them.

Comment: Good to hear.  If you found this answer correct, please accept it as correct.